# xam.plugin.geolocator used with xam.forms.maps makes the screen go black

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The next code is for make a custom pin with a given information of certain coordinates, I adapt it, so it can use the coordinates of the user

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CustomRenderer
{
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{
    //Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position position = null;
    public MapPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        App.position = Initialize().Result;

        var pin = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = new Position(App.position.Latitude, App.position.Longitude),
            Label = "Xamarin San Francisco Office",
            Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA",
            Id = "Xamarin",
            Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
        };
        customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };
        customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
        customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(App.position.Latitude,App.position.Longitude), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
    }

    public async Task<Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.Position> Initialize()
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 20;

        if (!locator.IsGeolocationAvailable || !locator.IsGeolocationEnabled)
        {
            try
            {
                return await locator.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
            }

            catch
            {

            }
        }

        try
        {
           return await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeout: TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000.0));
        } //miliseconds 

        catch { }
        return await locator.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
    }
}
```

}

But when I do this my screen go black, if I don't use this line of code

```
App.position = Initialize().Result;
```

and change position to numbers, the point in the map is displayed and the map works fine. Why does 
Initialize().Result don't work?

Comment: I check with breaking point, and it looks like the task never finish

Comment: Initialize is an async method and by calling Result you are blocking your UI. Try to use Initialize().GetAwaiter().GetResult() or ContinueWith.

Comment: I created a Task and wait for it to resolves any deadlocks. 

    Task task = Task.Run(async () => App.position =  await Initialize());
            task.Wait();

I dind't try ContinueWith but the first option you give me doesn't work, thanks for the help

Comment: Can you share your code somewhere like Github or bitbucket?

Comment: this is a very good page for know how to use xamarin.forms.maps https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-google-maps-api/ Now I am using a splash page to wait while I get the coordinates, other thing is if you change the timeout in locator.getpositionasync the result gets always in the time limit, so if you reduce it, it will takes less time